# @font-face not working on Firefox.

Tags: css, font-face

I have been trying to figure out why this @font-face isn't working on Firefox.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Eurostile';
  src: url("/fonts/eurostile_bold-webfont.eot");
  src: url("/fonts/eurostile_bold-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("/fonts/eurostile_bold-webfont.woff") format("woff"), url("/fonts/eurostile_bold-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"), url("/fonts/eurostile_bold-webfont.svg#eurostilebold") format("svg");
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal; }

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Eurostile';
  src: url("/fonts/eurostile-webfont.eot");
  src: url("/fonts/eurostile-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("/fonts/eurostile-webfont.woff") format("woff"), url("/fonts/eurostile-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"), url("/fonts/eurostile-webfont.svg#eurostileregular") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal; }
```

I'm trying to call it with:

```
font: 18px/1.5 "Eurostile",sans-serif;
```

Comment: how is it "not working"? Seeing weird chars or nothing at all? Tried the full URL?

Comment: Not working as in displaying the secondary font in the stack (sans-serif)

Comment: Full URL is http://asantiblack.com/dev.cfm

Comment: I meant: have you tried the full URL in the CSS @ your fonts, so it would be `src: url("http://asantiblack.com/fonts/eurostile_bold-webfont.eot");` for example, but the URL results a 404. Sure it's correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling your font like this:

```
.text {
    font-family: 'Eurostile', sans-serif;
    font-size:18px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is `font-family:Eurostile;` inside the `@font-face`. Then to call it you use the exact same thing. You don't need quotes.